# Material UI Icon Tabs with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to figure out how to add React Router to my bottom [Material UI tab bar](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#icon-tabs). I have two tabs which both open on the '/'. Ideally, I want the Counties tab to have a '/' path and the United States tab to have a '/usa' path.

Just want to clarify the other existing routes ('/state/:stateName' & '/country/countryName') under index.js are not suppose to show a the tab bar. These routes clicking on a country or state name in the body of the page. Tab bar should not be linking to these routes.

Here's an online demo of what I have so far: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-stallman-88e4e?from-embed)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.